# Set Array element from another array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want set value of array element from another array element in javascript. But both elements are changed! How change only `arr[1]`?

```
arr[0] = {i: 0};
arr[1] = arr[0];
arr[1]['summ'] = 0;
```

Results:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0: Object
  i: 0
  summ: 1
1: Object
  i: 0
  summ: 0
```

Comment: Is it Javascript ?

Comment: Upvote for editing your question :). Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both of them have same reference, so you should copy value of the object to the second object which has different reference. So try this trick:

```
arr[1] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[0]));
```

Comment: How is this solving the problem? The op mentioned that he wants to change only arr[1]. The value he wanted to set there was {i: 0}. So how do you know that was arr[0]'s value in the first place, even though the op specifically mentioned he does not want to put this value to arr[0]? And further, why are you stringifying arr[0] and then parsing it back to a JSON object???

Comment: @WebPauk your welcome. I strongly recommended you to (1) edit your question to be clear, (2) up-vote and accept the answer if solved your problem. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand anything from this question, but I will try my best. You have

```
arr[0] = {i: 0};
arr[1] = arr[0];
arr[1]['summ'] = 0;
```

where you set the value of `arr[0]`. Instead you want to change only `arr[1]`, so here you go:

```
arr[1] = {i: 0};
arr[1]['summ'] = 0;
```

If we need to set `arr[0]` to `arr[1]`, then

```
arr[1] = arr[0];
```

Comment: i need set arr[1] from arr[0]
i dont know the real value of arr[0]!!!
i set arr[0] = {i: 0} for example